# Cos'è "la Stella" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Per strada, lui ricominciò a parlare dei lati buoni dei Solara. Conoscevano, le disse, gente importante al comune, erano ammanigliati con **la Stella** e la Corona, coi missini.

Non capisco cosa intenda l'autrice con "la Stella" nel brano precedente. Ho cercato in [questa pagina di Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stella_(disambigua)) ma non ho saputo trovare niente che avesse senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato della "Stella" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

***[Stella e Corona](http://biellamonarchica.blogspot.it/)***  fa riferimento ai movimenti nostalgici della monarchia in italia.

> - I monarchici di Italia Reale, nel più assoluto rispetto delle leggi dello Stato, intendono mantenere viva una questione monarchica, nel dibattito sociale, politico e culturale del Paese, attraverso la partecipazione attiva alle elezioni e proporre, così, una riforma delle istituzioni ed un ripensamento dello Stato, per garantire la dignità, la sicurezza, le identità del nostro popolo, a partire dalle realtà dei nostri Comuni.
>   I Monarchici propongono uno Stato, quale naturale prosecuzione delle famiglie, dei Comuni, delle Comunità di lavoro, degli organi intermedi.

***La stella del simbolo fa riferimento a:***

> - ***[La Stella d'Italia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stella_d%27Italia)***, conosciuta popolarmente anche come Stellone, è una stella bianca a cinque punte che da molti secoli rappresenta la terra italiana. È il più antico simbolo patrio italiano, dato che risale all'antica Grecia.
> - Nei primi anni del XVI secolo iniziò ad essere associata con frequenza all'Italia turrita, personificazione nazionale allegorica della penisola italiana. La Stella d'Italia viene rievocata anche dall'emblema della Repubblica Italiana, dov'è sovrapposta a una ruota dentata d'acciaio e contornata da un ramo di quercia e da uno di ulivo.